# Virtualbox complete fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, virtualbox

I am running Windows via Virtualbox on my Macbook. It works fine. When I switch to fullscreen to screen the screen is actually full, but the windows windows does not spread out to the full extent. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that you have not installed the guest additions in your guest system.

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows):

> In the "Devices" menu in the virtual machine's menu bar, VirtualBox
>   has a handy menu item named "Install guest additions", which mounts
>   the Guest Additions ISO file inside your virtual machine. A Windows
>   guest should then automatically start the Guest Additions installer,
>   which installs the Guest Additions into your Windows guest. Other
>   guest operating systems (or if automatic start of software on CD is
>   disabled) need manual start of the installer.